# Using sum on two queries joined using UNION ALL

Tags: sql-server, union

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014. I have two queries that I have joined using Union. Each query gives me a total but I need to be able to get a total of those two queries. Therefore, take the values given in these two queries and add them together to give me my final number. The two queries are:

```
select sum(acct.balance) as 'Balance'
from acct
where 
acct.status <> 'closed' 

Union all

select sum(term.balance) as 'Balance'
from term
where 
term.status = 'active'
```

I have tried other suggestions posted on here but none have worked. My query should show me the balance of Acct.balance + term.balance.

Comment: The two answers below are essentially the same.  One is a CTE and one is a sub query, and both show how you can continue to build upon a previously existing query.  You could similarly have just added them, seeing as they are single values, as opposed to union-ing them.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, your problem is easy that you have only two values, so you even could have directly added them, instead of union-ing them.  I only give this example for completion and theory.

```
select (select sum(acct.balance) from acct where  acct.status <> 'closed' ) + (select sum(term.balance) from term where term.status = 'active') as Balance
```

I mention that because it seems like the union all is what got you stuck.  And yes, you can put that in a sub query or CTE, but in this case you don't even have a set, but just two values, since you aren't grouping by anything.

Other examples show CTE and subquery, which is how you can continue and build upon an existing query.  (Another option may be to create a view if it's going to get reused a lot, but again, that is overkill for your example.)

**When to use which?**

I prefer **CTE** when I'm going to join something in more than once.  For example, if I find and **rank** something, and then **join** the **prior** item to the **next** item. There are also other tricks with CTE's that go beyond that into areas like recursion.  (http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3910386/Tips-for-Using-Common-Table-Expressions.htm)

If I just have a query that I want to build upon, I often just make it a subquery as long as the code is pretty short and straight forward.

A nice thing about either a CTE or a sub query is that you can select that inner code, and run just that when you're trying to understand why you're seeing the actual results.

All that being said, I don't generally like to see subqueries with the select region, so how I'd actually write this would be closer to :

```
select sum(SubTotals.Balance) as Balance
from
(
    select sum(acct.balance) as Balance
    from acct
    where acct.status <> 'closed' 

    Union all

    select sum(term.balance) as Balance
    from term
    where term.status = 'active'

) SubTotals
```

I give that example with the comment that meaningful names are good.

Comment: Thank you for your information. It is very helpful. I have one more hiccup though. I need to list the data in dollar amount breakdowns. For Example, category 1 <$100,000, Cat. 2 $100K-$250K, cat. 3 $250K-$500K etc. I would like to find a way to do that with an SQL. I know there will be several sections to this in order to show all the categories but the first one would be the same and I could copy them to each subsequent query. Using this, I am trying to figure out how I can get a list where it will sort the Acct.balance+Term.Balance= <$100K in one total, then Cat. 2 in another etc.

Comment: Currerntly in the above, you have only one value.  You can can classify that into a category using a case statement.  (e.g. case when balance < 100000 then 'cat1' when balance between 100000 and 249999 then 'cat2' end ).   But I'm wondering if you actually want to be grouping by something (such as this categorization or etc), and perhaps we're missing details.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I need to show the balance of Acct+terms in each category as well as the number of accts in each. So I am trying to create a query that will do all that before I export to a spreadsheet. I would like to be able to have my SQL generate the total balance for accts and terms for each category (<$100k, $100K to $250K etc) so that it will just populate the tracking report I do in excel.

Comment: I know I can't add that parameter to the query for acct.balance and term.balance as it has to be based on the total combined balance and not the individual but when I try to expand on what you have above, it will not work. I am fairly new with SQLs but am trying to learn. I appreciate you taking the time to help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use CTE to do this

```
;with mycte as (
select 
sum(acct.balance) as 'Balance' 
from acct 
where acct.status <> 'closed'

Union all

select sum(term.balance) as 'Balance'
from term
where 
term.status = 'active'
)

Select 
sum(Balance) as total_balance
 from mycte
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. It is very helpful. I have one more hiccup though. I need to list the data in dollar amount breakdowns. For Example, category 1 <$100,000, Cat. 2 $100K-$250K, cat. 3 $250K-$500K etc. I would like to find a way to do that with an SQL. I know there will be several sections to this in order to show all the categories but the first one would be the same and I could copy them to each subsequent query. Using this, I am trying to figure out how I can get a list where it will sort the Acct.balance+Term.Balance= <$100K in one total, then Cat. 2 in another etc. .

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(t.balance) from 
(select balance
from acct
where 
acct.status <> 'closed' 

Union all

select balance
from term
where 
term.status = 'active') t
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations/comments to your answer. It'll make easier to understand its meaning.